# Why can a list in python be subtracted from the np.float64 type and the int type cannot be used?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

List operation problem
I don't know how this works, Can someone explain why?

```
import numpy as np

l=[]
for i in range(10):
  l.append(i+1)
  m=l - np.float64(1)    #This works fine
  n=l-2                # This will give an error
```

Comment: Did you look at the `m` result?  Or test things outside the loop?  `[1,2,3]+np.array(1)` versus `[1,2,3]+2`.  `np.float64(1)` creates an `ndarray` like object, and with it all the rules of `numpy` array priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with `numpy` rather than the subtracted element being a `float` versus an `int`. Subtracting `np.int64(1)` also works fine.

As to why it works. The result of the subtraction is a `numpy` array. I think the ordinary Python `list` is first cast to a `numpy` array, and then the `numpy` `int` or `float` is subtracted.

However, you cannot subtract and `int` or `float` from an ordinary list.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [1, 2, 3]
np_list = np.array(lst)

# # fails, since you cannot subtract int or float from list
lst - 1
lst - 1.0

# works fine, since element(s) is (are) cast to numpy element
np_list - 1
np_list - 1.0
lst - np.int64(1)
lst - np.float64(1)
np_list - np.int64(1)
np_list - np.float64(1)
```